# Lego mindstorms ev3 colour sensor always in reflect mode

Tags: lego-mindstorms-ev3

When I'm using the colour sensor in Mindstorms EV3, the sensor stays on the reflect mode. I can change it to colour mode in port view, but when I exit out and go back in port view, it changes back. Same when I power the EV3 brick off. So how do you get the sensor to stay in colour detection mode?